# El metodo data64 hace mas rapido al navagador al cargar las imagenes?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

Estoy haciendo un chat con ajax y no se es mas fácil usar data64 para hacer al chat mas ligero y así no se vea la ruta del archivo ejemplo `./uploads/5rtfgygyg-image.png`

```
$image = 'myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($image);
$dataUri = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: un dato: al usar Base64, el peso aumenta en un 30% aprox.

Comment: fredyfx gracias pero entonces como baja el peso de imagenes para usarse en un chatroom sabes?

Comment: de nada :D puedes comprimirlas mediante "thumbnails", es decir, si tienes imagenes de 300x300, puede generar otra de 50x50 manteniendo la escala y al usaralas en la sala de chat, llamas a la de menor tamaño, me dejo entender?

Comment: pero como no lo vi gracias por tu ayuda amigo :)

Comment: de nada hermano/a, estamos para servir, por cierto, queda pendiente la otra parte de tu pregunta: "ocultar la ruta de las imagenes", ya seguro alguien que sabe cómo usar los .htaccess aparecerá :D

Comment: si tengo miedo de que metan un archivo en la ruta UPLOADS y asi saquen la informacion no sabes como ocultar esa ruta ? ya para puder dormir en paz ########hack####### miedo de ellos si XD

Comment: filtra adecuadamente las subidas de archivos, revisa extensiones y MIME Types del archivo, en el servidor asegúrate que dicha carpeta de subida tenga el acceso denegado a la ejecucion de scripts (PHP, .sh por ejemplo).